# How to write a test suite for nose

Tags: python-2.7, nose, test-suite, unit-testing

If i want to write an unit test, I just drop a file in my `test/` subdirectory with my test class heriting from `unittest.TestCase`.

Now i want to use such pattern for a test suite: I have a python file in `test/` with a  class (extending `unittest.TestSuite`) which reads a file and generate test from it. I've already the code for parsing the file and generate the TestCase from them.

But nose does not detect this class. How can I make nose aware of this file and generate the tests from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the version of python you are using. With Python 2.7+ you can define a [`load_tests`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) function in your module which will be called to create the TestSuite for the module.

However, nose ignores the load_tests protocol. If you have nose2 then it features a [plugin](http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/loadtests.html) for the load tests protocol.

Otherwise, you create a blank `TestCase` and populate with generated test functions. For instance:

```
import unittest

data = ["a", "b", "c"] # or from whatever source you want

class GeneratedTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.correct = "b"

def setup_module():
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        test_driver = create_driver(d)
        name ="test_generated{}".format(i)
        setattr(GeneratedTests, name, test_driver)

def create_driver(d):
    def test_driver(self):
        self.assertEqual(d, self.correct)
    return test_driver

setup_module()
```

One final way you can do this is to use the [subtest context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests). This is only available in 3.4+. However, you can find a poor man's replacement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783861/adding-test-methods-dynamically-using-decorator/26785209#26785209). Hopefully, it should help you structure your generated tests in a more readable fashion.

Comment: Ideally I want to target python 2.7 for compatibility issues.

Comment: This is definitively what I'm looking for but for python 2.7 and nose.